# Form wont submit after correct email validation jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, email

So my form throws up the correct error when no email is given. But when a correct email is put into the field, it wont submit. Where am I going wrong here? Thanks for any advice and help!

```
var myEmailRegEx = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;


$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submitbutton").click(function(e){
        var none_answered = true;
        var eMailToTest = $('#email').val();
            if(!myEmailRegEx.test(eMailToTest)) { 
                e.preventDefault();
                none_answered = true;
                $('#email').addClass('error');
                $('#texthere').html("Please provide a correct email");
            } 
           else {
               $('#email').removeClass('error');
               return true;
            }
     });
 });

<style type="text/css">

.error
{
    color:red;
}

#texthere
{
    color:red;
}

</style>

<body>
    <form>  
        <label id="email" class="req"><span>*</span>Email:</label>
        <input id="email" class="req" name="email" value="" type="email"></br>          
        <div id="texthere"></div>

        <input id="submitbutton" type="submit" value="submit" formaction="http://www.utah.edu/">
    </form> 

</body>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You did a few mistakes.

Use event submit on forms (not click event)

You used id attribute on label and email. ID can be used only once on page.

```
var eMailToTest = $('#email').val();
```

It returned value of first element with ID email. So it's label (which has no value). You want input element instead.

Here is the working code.

HTML:

```
<form>  
        <label for="email" class="req"><span>*</span>Email:</label>
        <input id="email" class="req" name="email" value="" type="text"><br>          
        <div id="texthere"></div>

        <input id="submitbutton" type="submit" value="submit" formaction="http://www.utah.edu/">
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
var myEmailRegEx = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;

(function(){
    $("form").on('submit', function(e){
        var eMailToTest = $('#email').val();
            if(!myEmailRegEx.test(eMailToTest)) { 
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#email').addClass('error');
                $('#texthere').html("Please provide a correct email");
            } else {
                $('#email').removeClass('error');
            }
     });
 })();
```

Also none_answered variable is redundant here.

[Working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/tQbJ3/)

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 3):

You have duplicate IDs, for the label and input field. Because of that the value of `eMailToTest` was always blank.

```
<label for="email" class="req"><span>*</span>Email:</label>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/EF294/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to do like this:

```
$("#submitbutton").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var none_answered = true;
    var eMailToTest = $('#email').val();
    if (!myEmailRegEx.test(eMailToTest)) {
        none_answered = true;
        $('#email').addClass('error');
        $('#texthere').html("Please provide a correct email");
    } else {
        $('#email').removeClass('error');
        $('form').submit();
    }
});
```

Also, seem like your `none_answered` variable is redundant here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this change id of label

```
<form action="http://www.utah.edu/">
    <label class="req"><span>*</span>Email:</label> // Here duplicate id removed
    <input id="email" class="req" name="email" value="" type="email">
    </br>
    <div id="texthere"></div>
    <input id="submitbutton" type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Script

```
var myEmailRegEx = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
$("#submitbutton").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var none_answered = true;
    var eMailToTest = $('#email').val();
        if(!eMailToTest.match(myEmailRegEx)) { 
            none_answered = true;
            $('#email').addClass('error');
            $('#texthere').html("Please provide a correct email");
            console.log('if')
        } 
       else {
           console.log('else')
           $('#email').removeClass('error');
           $(this).closest('form').submit();
        }
 });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2QKe9/3/)